# Safari: Submit is one pixel lower

Tags: css

I have issue with my submit button. It is one pixel lower than txt input, but only in Safari. Chrome and Firefox are just fine.

```
input[type=text] {
height: 45px;
width: 238px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ebebeb;
border: 1px solid #cecece;
border-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
box-shadow:         0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
color: #999999;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Noticia Text', serif;
padding-left: 20px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#subscribe {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #3eb0ef;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3eb0ef 0%, #1b8dd4 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3eb0ef), color-stop(100%,#1b8dd4));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3eb0ef 0%,#1b8dd4 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3eb0ef 0%,#1b8dd4 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3eb0ef 0%,#1b8dd4 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3eb0ef 0%,#1b8dd4 100%);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3eb0ef', endColorstr='#1b8dd4',GradientType=0 );
border-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #1082c8;
height: 47px;
width: 107px;
font-family: 'Noticia Text', serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

and HTML:

```
<form name="subscription" method="post">
  <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address"><input name="subscribe" id="subscribe" value="Notify me" type="submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SV3VS/

Comment: And yes I am using normalize.css.

Comment: I look at it in safari V5.1.5(7534.55.3) and it work fine

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3M1n270Z0L41 ..thats what I see in safari.

Comment: not on my side, could be just a glitch for the version you have. Note that I test it in safari under windows platform.

Comment: Well, my friend sees it too in his Safari (both on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/ERhLP/

I could see the blip on Safari as well so I tried explicitly setting the height of the input box and the submit button and changed them to an even number.

```
input#email{
height:48px;
}    

#subscribe {
....
height: 48px;
....
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3h0j1n3v1w0c - now it looks like this on both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: At 100%, it looks good to me with Safari 6.0.3 and Mac Chrome 26.0.1410.43.  How does it look to you if you don't magnify? Remember that viewing at other than 100% can sometimes throw alignment off by a pixel or so.

Comment: Safari: http://cl.ly/image/0b3Y411v130D, Chrome: http://cl.ly/image/0M021q25181M - yeah, sorry i just tried to point that the problem is still there. Chrome 26.0.1410.43, Safari 6.0.3 OSX 10.8.3

Comment: It just doesn't want to co-operate!

Comment: Well, there must be some solution, even javascript one.